# Footer in OWC spread sheet control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I am using OWC spreadSheet  control and want to add footer while save and load spread sheet.Is it possible then please provide me any example that will help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you supply some code your working on? Where does ASP Classic come into play?

Comment: using OWC spreadsheet control in classic asp and .net aslo